# In ASP.NET are Web Pages the new "Classic ASP"?

Tags: asp.net, razor

In ASP.NET we have 3 technologies to choose:

- Web Forms
- MVC
- Web Pages

Both Web Forms and MVC represent steps forward in web development.

However Web Pages goes back to the mix of HTML and code (cshtml/vbhtml files) just like classic ASP (HTML + VB).

Being the separation of HTML and code the workhorse of ASP.NET, can we consider Web Pages a step behind?

Thank you

Comment: my friend, those kind of questions are way off topic on stackoverflow, plus you can find plenty of info on that on the official websites.

Comment: @Banana: it's usefull know what technology more experienced people use. If you have a clue about pros and cons of web pages I'll appreciate.

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919743/performance-wise-is-mvc-better-than-web-forms-in-asp-net)